# using if loop in docker file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, devops

```
RUN if [ "$AUTH_MS_PROFILE" = "test" ]; then RUN ["mvn", "verify"]; fi
```

so, the case is am trying to have two images for prod and test since I don't need to run integration test @ prod so, am using build-arg to set dev and test profile 
I need to have an if loop  if the input is test it should test else it shouldn't

Comment: so, did you try ? what is the problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile if else condition with external arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments)

Answer (score 3):

I would move all such conditions to a `build_internal.sh` file

```
if [ "$AUTH_MS_PROFILE" = "test" ]; then 
   mvn verify
fi
```

Copy this file inside and run it inside the Dockerfile. If you want to use your approach then you just need to use

```
RUN if [ "$AUTH_MS_PROFILE" = "test" ]; then mvn verify ; fi
```

Comment: At seem cleaner to keep all the configuration in the docker file rather than putting some in a bash script, so i am curious about the reasoning behind this.
Do docker files not support loops, or is this considered a better way of doing things?

Comment: @wobbily_col, that depends on how readable your conditions are