# RUN npm command inside if statements within dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

i have a dockerfile which is built with an ARG (name of the git branch). 
I want to run 2 if statements which test the name of the git branch: So if it is the test branch then it will run  "npm run test", if it is master branch then "npm run build". 
I've tried this but it does not work :

RUN if [ "$GIT_BRANCH" = "test" ] ; then CMD npm test ; fi

RUN if  [ "$GIT_BRANCH" = "master" ] ; then CMD npm build ; fi

It works with echo but not with npm commands. why ?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RUN inside a conditional statement in Dockerfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51518087/run-inside-a-conditional-statement-in-dockerfile)

Comment: In what way does it not work??

Comment: @larsks it says /bin/sh: 1: CMD: not found
The command '/bin/sh -c if [ "$GIT_BRANCH" = test" ] ; then CMD npm test ; fi' returned a non-zero code: 127

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case someone has the same problem one day :
if you want to run an npm command inside if statements within a dockerfile, the key is to write:

```
RUN if [ "$GIT_BRANCH" = "test" ] ; then  /usr/bin/npm test --force ; fi

RUN if [ "$GIT_BRANCH" = "master" ] ; then /usr/bin/npm build --force ; fi
```

And it will work. The --force is essential otherwise it will launch a git error.