# Is there a way to use If condition in Dockefile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am new to `docker`, I am looking for a way to execute a command in docker container depends on the environment.

In Dockerfile, I have 2 commands, command_a and command_b. If the `env = 'prod'` run command_a, else command_b. How can I achieve this?

I tried like below:

```
RUN if [ $env = "prod" ] ; then echo command_a; else echo cpmmand_b; fi;
```

How can I achieve the desired behaviour?

PS:
I know that echo should not be there.

Comment: I think you've got the right way to do that. Docker doesn't provide conditional statements

Comment: And what happened when you tried that?

Comment: Well, it evaluates the condition in the RUN statement, and everything goes like in bash or shell

Comment: @Henry - It ofcourse just printed  :D It did not execute that.

Comment: So basically it worked as intended. Now just replace the `echo command_a` with the command you want to run.

Comment: If you want to template your Dockerfile like a boss, you can use python with an `ini` file, `configparser` module, and then  `jinja2`. You can replace the config file with any other way to parse configuration. This is how I do when I have a lot of conditional statements in my Dockerfile. And this way I can include blocks and not only evaluate a condition in a RUN statement

Comment: @Henry - I had already tried that but did not work. But what worked for me is setting up the commands in variables and then replacing `echo command_a` with a variable name, worked like a charm. I will post it as a answer after sometime if I don't find any other alternatives.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile if else condition with external arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments)

Comment: Just to note, best practice is generally to run the same image in all environments and control “dev” or “prod” with environment variables.

Comment: Why would you link to those 2 questions? Even if `env` is given as build argument, user can still refer to it as `$env` and test its value with `if [ "$env" = "foo" ] ; then ... ; else ... ; fi ;`.  I don't see what changes being in Dockerfile implies? Could you explain it a little ?

Comment: Put the logic into a shell script file, copy it into the image and run it there.

Answer (score 3):

Docker 17.05 and later supports a kind of conditionals using multi-stage build and build args. Have a look at https://medium.com/@tonistiigi/advanced-multi-stage-build-patterns-6f741b852fae

From the blog post:

```
ARG BUILD_VERSION=1
FROM alpine AS base
RUN ...
FROM base AS branch-version-1
RUN touch version1
FROM base AS branch-version-2
RUN touch version2
FROM branch-version-${BUILD_VERSION} AS after-condition
FROM after-condition 
RUN ...
```

And then use `docker build --build-arg BUILD_VERSION=value ...`