# Separate Dockerfile for dav and prod

Tags: docker

I am new in Docker so please do not blame me :)

Is there a way to create two different Dockerfiles inherits from one? 
Example, we have to have 2 environment: develop and production. Theirs base is the same:

```
FROM gcc
# it's just an example which shows the same base packets for both environment
RUN apt install lib-boost
```

For "develop" I have to install some utilities like gdb, valgrind etc.
For "production" I have to build an application. It thought to use "multi stage builds", but it runs steps in Dockerfile consistently. How I should do if I do not want to build an application in "develop"?

The first build the base image:

`build -t base_image .`

And then for each Dockerfile use it?

```
# for develop
FROM base_image
RUN apt install gdb
```

```
# for prod
FROM base_image
RUN make
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile if else condition with external arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments)

Comment: Your own suggestion will work just fine ..

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example I'm currently using.

Base image Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim as base

RUN apt update
RUN apt install --no-install-recommends -y git-core build-essential \
 && apt autoclean
# ...
```

Prod image Dockerfile:

```
FROM your-registry/base:0.0.0 as prod

# your code
# ...
```

Hope, it'll be helpful for you.