# Adding files to docker container based on a docker-compose Environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, run-app

I have a large set of test files (3.2 gb) that I only want to add to the container if an environment variable (DEBUG) is set. For testing locally I set these in a docker-compose file.

So far, I've added the test data folder to a .dockerignore file and tried the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments) in my Dockerfile without any success.

I've also tried running the `cp` command from within a `run_app.sh` which i call in my docker file:

```
cp local/folder app/testdata
```

but get `cp: cannot stat 'local/folder': No such file or directory`, i guess because it's trying to find a folder that exists on my local machine inside the container?

This is my docker file:

```
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app/

ARG DEBUG
RUN if [ "x$DEBUG" = "True" ] ; echo "Argument not provided" ; echo "Argument is $arg" ; fi

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
USER nobody

ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE ${PORT}

CMD /uus/run_app.sh
```

Comment: I'm afraid the only solution here would be to have two Dockerfiles -- one for debugging purposes, the other one for production/whatever. You could write a shell script, which would build the specific image, but afaik you won't be able to use conditions inside Dockerfile itself.

Answer (score 0):

If it's really just for testing, and it's in a clearly named isolated directory like `testdata`, you can inject it using a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

Remove the `ARG DEBUG` and the build-time option to copy the content into the image.  When you run the container, run it with

```
docker run \
  -v $PWD/local/folder:/app/testdata:ro \
  ...
```

This makes that host folder appear in that container directory, read-only so you don't accidentally overwrite the test data for later runs.

Note that this hides whatever was in the image on that path before; hence the "if it's in a separate directory, then..." disclaimer.