# Change base image based on condition in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-build

I want to send an argument USE_ALPINE to docker file
if it is true i will use alpine image
if it is false i will use debian image

the default value for USE_ALPINE i want to set it to false.

Comment: https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/use-arg-dockerfile-dynamic-image-specification

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make use of [combination of ARG and FROM in Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact).

You can use variables declared in ARG inside FROM statement.

```
ARG  APP_IMAGE=alpine:latest
FROM ${APP_IMAGE}
CMD  /path/to/mycode
```

And can also override this value using [--build-arg option of docker build command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg).

```
docker build -t myapp:v1 --build-arg APP_IMAGE=busybox:latest .
```

Comment: but the requirement is to use a boolean do we have any possibility to do so?

Comment: Can;t find any in-built support for boolean flag in docker build. But you can try something with combination of multi-stage builds and arguments. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/60820156