# Dockerfile how to make start command different between dev and prod?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

I have a TypeScript Node app. I have a dev and start npm scritps:

```
"dev": "ts-node-dev src/index.ts",
"build": "npm run test:ci && tsc",
"start": "node dist/index"
```

When developing I watch changes on the .ts files and when running in production I want to run the .js files from the dist dir (which is generated using the npm build script).

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./ 

RUN npm i --only=prod

COPY . . 

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

When its running on dev env its good, but on production the CMD command should be like that:

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Also the `RUN npm i --only-prod` command also needs to be changed respectively.

How to make it adjustable to dev vs prod?

Comment: `docker run ... npm start`?

Comment: @super what do you mean by that?

Comment: When you run the container, you can override the command it should run by simply supplying it on the command line when you start the container.

Comment: I am using kubernetes which runs the default command on the image, not manually via the cli.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile if else condition with external arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments)

Comment: @Raz Kubernetes can be configured to do whatever you want. If you are using a specific setup and need help with that you should include that in your question. Maybe you should take a refresher of the [tour] and [ask], plus how to make a [mre].

Comment: @derpirscher not sure. this is not a solution, but a "wire end"

Answer (score 1):

In kubernetes you can overwrite the default command `args`:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
[...]
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: CONTAINER-NAME
        image: IMAGE-NAME
        args: [
          "npm",
          "start" ]
```

See the kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod).

The detailed implementation depend on the deployment system you're using:

- You can write two different `.yaml` files, one for the development and one for the production environment.
- If you're deploying with helm, you can set this configuration in a value file per environment.
- You can also use Kustomize as described in [this example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/#customizing).

Comment: They talk about arguments and env variables that can use to  maybe solve the issue I asked about, but neither your answer or thier docs answer directly my question. I want to adjust the start command from dev to prod. How can it be done? you gave only one command which is not conditional.

Comment: I've listed some possible options.