# Docker: install package on condition?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to install package on condition, when building image?

I have my base image and I only want to install some packages when running tests. This way I could reuse same image, even when running tests.

For example

```
FROM some-image
RUN pip3 intall-something
# Install this if environment variable (or ARG) `TEST` is used?
RUN pip3 install websocket-client==1.2.1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dockerfile if else condition with external arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43654656/dockerfile-if-else-condition-with-external-arguments)

Comment: @LinFelix yes it did, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
FROM alpine
ARG cmd1
RUN ${cmd1}
CMD ["ash","-c","sleep 3600"]
```

`docker build --build-arg cmd1="apk add curl" -t myapp .`

`docker run -it --rm myapp curl -k https://www.google.com` # ok, curl was installed and working

`docker build --build-arg cmd1="true" -t myapp .`

`docker run -it --rm myapp curl -k https://www.google.com` # curl not found as expected

You can tweak "cmd1" as you see fit. When you don't want to do anything, `true` is like a noop.

Comment: I used similar approach, just also added if/else in `RUN`

Comment: if/else is nice to have consider a simple `true` is a noop already, it is cleaner compare to a ternary statement in a Dockerfile. But that's up to what you need.