# Modify ARG value in Windows docker container

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to build a docker container with the atlassian-build-runner but make it configurable to specify either latest version (w/o suffix) or latest version using a suffix using the following snippet:

```
ARG BASE_IMAGE=mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8
FROM $BASE_IMAGE

...

# Install Atlassian build, specify --build-arg=-x.y to use different version than latest release
ARG BUILDER_VERSION=""
ADD https://product-downloads.atlassian.com/software/bitbucket/pipelines/atlassian-bitbucket-pipelines-runner$BUILDER_VERSION.zip bitbucket-pipelines-runner.zip
RUN powershell -Command Expand-Archive bitbucket-pipelines-runner.zip C:\bitbucket-pipelines-runner
```

I would like the user to not have to specify a leading dash (-) in the build argument. Any pointers on how to do this on a Windows container?

I already tried modifying the environment variable in PowerShell (default shell for the Windows base image) to no avail:

```
ARG BUILDER_VERSION=""
ENV BUILDER_VERSION=$BUILDER_VERSION
ENV if ([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($Env:BUILDER_VERSION)) { return "-" + $Env:BUILDER_VERSION}
```

But it keeps failing the download since the dash is missing when a version build argument is supplied. Any pointers?

Comment: I suspect this isn't possible: you can't run conditionals or other code inside an `ENV` statement, and Compose only supports very limited [variable expansion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#variable-substitution) syntax.

Comment: It seems with linux containers some form of conditional statement is possible, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43656644/2186184

Comment: That answer has an ordinary Bourne shell conditional _within a single `RUN` statement_; that can't set persistent environment variables, and anything it sets (Bourne shell `export` directive) would get reset at the end of the `RUN` statement.